# Assert.Fail does not fail test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am using VS 2008 for unit testing. Even if my code calls

```
Assert.Fail("some message");
```

Test passess ??

and even

`Assert.IsTrue(false);` this also passes test.

How is this possible. I am expecting test to fail . i want to forcefully fail it .

Please help !

Comment: Ensure you are doing a Debug Build?

Comment: Maybe the code you're testing is so good, it can't fail! I wish I knew how to write code like that, I'm blowing up unit tests all the time..

Comment: Chuck Norris in action:)

Comment: Actually i am unit testing workflow custom activities. for negative test case i expect WorkflowTerminated event to be raised. In that event i use Assert.Fail() to fail that test.

Comment: Ensure you are not using a try/catch method that catch AssertException etc.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you are catching exceptions somewhere in the test code. Assert class uses exceptions to fail the test, so if you are catching it the test passes.

Please paste the code for more accurate answer.

Comment: that'd be my guess too - AssertFailedException FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Assert class built into .NET? If so, I suspect `TRACE` was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when I click "run tests", I've seen the test engine build in Release configuration but then proceed to run tests against an older Debug configuration build.  I would call that a bug in the VS2008 test engine.  Anyway, try cleaning your Debug AND Release folders and running it again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without knowing more about what you're doing, but it sounds like you're expecting the .NET classes to work like the NUnit classes -- can't be sure -- but if you are, that will never work.

The .NET classes only work if Trace is defined (view the Project Properties, the click the Build tab, then click the "Define TRACE constant"). -- But for Unit Tests this is not helpful -- those classes do not throw exceptions or otherwise fail unit tests... they pop up message boxes for those subscribing to the "debug later" mantra.

If you want Assert.Fail to fail a *unit test* you'll need a unit testing framework that provides a class which does this (again, like NUnit).  Please, let us know what testing framework you're using (or not using?) and we'll be able to help you a bit more if you're still having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when a Method was async but the call did not await it. I removed async from the method and it Failed perfectly.

I realise this question is old but that was the anser for me in VS2022.